# Prove or disprove the following statement:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove the following statement:
Suppose $n \in \mathbb Z$. If $n^3 + 2$ is odd, then $n^2$  is odd.

Any idea on how to start this proof?

Comment: If n^3+2 is odd, is n^3 odd or even? What about n? n^2?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \, {\rm mod}\ 2\!:\ n^2\equiv n\,\Rightarrow\,n^3\equiv n,\, $ so it is equivalent to: $\ n+2\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\, n\,$ odd.

Answer (score 1):

If $n^3 + 2$ is odd, then $n^3$ must be odd too (obviously).

if $n^3$ is odd, so if we took the unique prime factorization of this number (from the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic), 2 is not one of the factors in this factorization.

Now, because the prime factorization of $n^3$ has the exact same primes factors as $n$ (but only their exponents are three times the exponents of the primes in $n$), then 2 is not one of the factors in the factorization of $n$ either, meaning $n$ is odd.

For the same reason, if $n$ is odd, $n^2$ is odd (because 2 won't be one of the primes in the uniqe primes factorization).